# Sublime Text 3 - Replace character in particular lines

Tags: sublime-text-2, sublime-text-3

I have a file with content like this (its a movie subtitle file)

```
00:21:39.168 --> 00:21:45.585
There will be 23 days, giving
00:21:48.960 --> 00:21:54.126
We'll talk, Oscar.
Come back soon.
00:22:37.376 --> 00:22:42.293
No, there is no problem.
We'll talk, Oscar.
```

In every line beginning with 0 (zero), I want to replace the dot (9th and 26th characters) with a comma.

or simply put,. I need the time format to be xx:xx:xx,xxx

Answer (score 1):

- Click Find->Replace...
- Activate Regular expression (the star on the left)
- Find: (\d\d:\d\d:\d\d)\.
- Replace: \1,
- Click Replace All

\d matches any digit, \1 is the expression enclosed in brackets.

More info: http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/search_and_replace/search_and_replace_overview.html